# Fastcall in 64 bit

Tags: unix, 64-bit, x86-64, stdcall, fastcall

I've been reading up on the differences in 32bit calling conventions. The `fastcall` vs. `stdcall` ordeal that is.

From what I read there was great confusion with the two conventions, and 64 bit was standardized to avoid this confusion.

I have to ask, why was `fastcall` chosen?

Also, since `fastcall` and `stdcall` are win32 terms, what is the UNIX term for function calling that does or does not use registers for passing arguments?

Comment: It isn't exactly fastcall, it is the "we've got 8 more registers, let use 'em" calling convention.

Comment: @hansPassant there really is no saving for using registers for arg passing since you usually have to backup the registers beforehand onto the stack. Fastcall-style calling is only faster in very specific situations.

Comment: You assume they have to be "backed-up".  That's not a correct assumption in general.  The code generator can treat them as scratch or reload them from memory.  The "let's use 'em" scheme is not "let's use 'em all".

Comment: @hansPassant point taken. I guess I see more of a problem with the 'callee' needing to use the registers anyway and having to back up args on the stack, unless it's a very simple function that is.

Comment: There's not such thing as '64-bit fastcall'.  fastcall is purely an artifact of old 32-bit x86.

Answer (score 3):

[x86 Calling Conventions - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) provides a list.

The common calling convention on x86-32 is `cdecl`.  GCC provides a function attribute `__attribute__((regparm(n)))` to indicate that `n` arguments are passed by register, but this is not the same as `fastcall`.  Either way, arguments are passed in callee-clobberable registers, so there is no additional cost (and saves the effort of adding stack space for arguments then cleaning it up) for function calls relative to `cdecl` (for `regparm`) and `stdcall` (for `fastcall`).

To aid in your confusion, the x86-64 calling conventions on Windows and Linux are different both from those on x86-32 and from each other.  Neither is `fastcall`, although both use a significant number of registers to pass arguments.

Comment: I'm more upset about BSD, since they have always had stack based calling, which is both simpler and saves CPU time since you don't need to backup registers beforehand. From what I understand of what you said it would seem that register passing is not required in 64bit?

Comment: @Hawken: `regparm` and `fastcall` use registers that are callee-clobbered so they need to be caller-saved even under `cdecl` and `stdcall` – what CPU time is lost?  Currently there are no non-default x86-64 calling conventions in use by C compilers.  You can see [System V Application Binary Interface \ AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) and [MSDN | Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) for what's currently in use.

Comment: Even the FreeBSD dev-handbook states that register passing is slower. I'm inclined to believe them since FreeBSD devs are likely to have side by side register/stack passing programs for testing since they often port Linux code. Besides one would assume that you need to write passed values to the stack anyway since you'll be using `%e_x` registers in your instructions. Unless your function is only calling another function.